# Rewriting GroupBy[{elem1,elem2,…},spec,red] into GroupBy[spec] , how to apply reduction?

Tags: refactoring

I'm currently using this version of [GroupBy](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

> GroupBy[{elem1,elem2,…},spec,red]
>
> applies the function red to reduce lists of values that are generated.

I want to rewrite my function with this one:

> GroupBy[spec]
>
> represents an operator form of GroupBy that can be applied to an expression.

**How do I apply the reduction ("red") I could before?**

Alternatively, what other way is there to rewrite this with postfix operators so it's easier to read:

```
GroupBy[
 Flatten[Map[MapIndexed[{#1, First[#2]} &],votes],1],
 First -> Last ,
 Map[Last[#]*voteCounter[secondVote,First[#]]&]@*Tally @* Sort
]
```

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
Flatten[Map[MapIndexed[{#1, First[#2]} &],votes],1] // GroupBy[something]
```

Comment: `GroupBy[#,spec,red]&`?

Comment: @LukasLang That didn't work initially because I was already inside an anonymous function, but I rewrote it with functions and it works. If you submit it as answer I'll set it as accepted.